# How would I get rid of sharp spikes from a shape? Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello I am working on a logo idea but am struggling to remove a part of my image. I'd like to know how to remove this since I have had the same problem a few times and can't seem to find a way to overcome it.

Here's the image, the red boxes show the parts I'd like to remove.
https://i.gyazo.com/164c13a10b8cae46cbc21f86c2082a6c.png

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

My advice would be to outline your shape and manually edit those edges for the nicest and most finished look. Also make sure you don't have extra anchor points on those corners.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for the very delayed response. After a few days of this being up I assumed it'd go unanswered. I was so pleased to be proven wrong.